# Binding function keys to CTRL in Emacs

Tags: ubuntu, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

Is there a way in Emacs (version 24.2.1) to bind a function key to the CTRL key?  For example, I want to be able to type something like < F11 >-x < F11 >-f to open a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a non-control key into a control key is not possible from within Emacs. I think this must be done at the OS level.

On Ubuntu, you should be able to do this through [xkeycaps](http://www.jwz.org/xkeycaps/), available from the repositories. Run the program, left click on the control key, select 'duplicate key', then select the F11 key. The F11 key will now respond as another control key. Note that this will be in effect for all programs, not just Emacs.

Comment: This will have to do for now.  I could use `extra-keyboard-modifiers` to make a function key toggle Ctrl- and Meta- on and off, but it looks like it's not possible for another key to fully simulate Ctrl or Meta in Emacs without modifying its low-level input-handling code because it generates different keyboard events depending on what modifiers are held down.